# switching solenoid through transformer

Tags: transformer

I need to control 4 solenoid valves concurrently. I have 1-120vac and 3-24vac in my toolbox.  Incoming signal from thermostat is 120vac.  Is it permissable to tap the signal to to the 120v solenoid through a 120/24 x-former to activate the other three 24v solenoids or would there be a problem with the fields in the transformer and solenoids expanding/collapsing together when switching occurs?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem using the transformer to adapt the 120VAC down to use by the three 24VAC valves. Just make sure that you select the transformer with adequate secondary current rating to supply the three valves.

Do take a look at the thermostat though and make sure that its output switch or contacts are capable of handling the load of the one valve plus the transformer. All of these loads are inductive and can arc contacts if mechanical switches or contacts are in use.